# calling remote function using php soap

Tags: php, zend-framework, soap

I am trying to use soap in php and tried lots of different things and still no result.
It is service for sending SMS :
I used this code :

```
    $soapURL = "http://sms.magfa.com/services/urn:SOAPSmsQueue?wsdl" ;
    $soapParameters = Array('login' => "username", 'password' => "password") ;
    $soapFunction = "enqueue" ;
    $soapFunctionParameters = Array('domain' => 'domain', 'messageBodies' =>array("hello world"),'recipientNumbers'=>array('number'),'senderNumbers'=>array('sender')) ;
    $soapClient = new SoapClient($soapURL, $soapParameters);
    $soapResult = $soapClient->__soapCall($soapFunction, $soapFunctionParameters) ;
```

And got this error :

```
org.xml.sax.SAXException: No deserializer defined for array type {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known conflict between NuSoap and php standard soapclient . you should use the special version of nusoap that solved that problem .
http://code.google.com/p/nusoap-for-php5/